# Xpages source formatting

Tags: xpages

I wonder if there is anything more advanced for source formatting of Xpages than what is built-in to the editor. In particular I would like to remove white space from the code.

Anything out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the "Clear all blank lines" option in the DDE File > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor. There are a couple options there you may find of use, such as ensuring "Insert whitepsace before closing empty end-tags" is un-checked and whether you choose to "Preserve whitespace in tags with PCDATA content". It may not be "advanced", but is usually serves me well.

Reminder, XPage design element formatting (XPages, Custom Controls) is for readability only, as they get compiled into Java classes on project build (visible in Project Explorer, under Local > xsp).

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the setting I am using, too (and I motivated my colleagues to use it, too). My favorite is the "split multiple attributes..." thing as it makes the XML code more readable.

Comment: @OliverBusse Exactly. The fact that one can look at the code and have no room for doubt as to what properties are set to what value is excellent.

Comment: Split multiple attributes is great. Thanks for all suggestions here.